# Keep all columns in MIN / MAX query, but return 1 result

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm sure I've done this before, but seem to have forgotten how..

I'm trying to filter a recordset so that I get just the 1 record, so for example, if this is my table called **TableA**:

```
|  ID  |  User |  Type  |   Date   |
------------------------------------
|  1   | Matt  | Opened | 1/8/2014 |
|  2   | Matt  | Opened | 2/8/2014 |
|  3   | Matt  | Created| 5/8/2014 |
|  4   | John  | Opened | 1/8/2014 |
|  5   | John  | Created| 2/8/2014 |
```

I'd want to filter it so I get the `MIN` of Date where the User is "Matt" and the Type is "Opened".

The result set needs to include the ID field and return just the 1 record, so it would look like this:

```
|  ID  |  User |  Type  |   Date   |
------------------------------------
|  1   | Matt  | Opened | 1/8/2014 |
```

I'm struggling with getting past the GROUPBY requirement when selecting the ID field... this seems to ignore MIN of Date and return more than 1 record.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Use `TOP` and `ORDER BY`:

```
select top 1 *
from table
where user = "Matt" and type = "Opened"
order by date asc;
```

**Edit**: changed order by from `desc` to `asc` as this achieves the `MIN` effect I'm after.

Comment: order by should be `asc` (ascending) to get the effect of MIN on dates I think.

Answer (score 1):

Another way is by finding the `min` or `max` date per `user` and `type` then join the result back to the main table

```
SELECT A.ID,
       A.USER,
       A.Type,
       A.Date
FROM   yourtable A
       INNER JOIN (SELECT USER,
                          Type,
                          Min(Date) Date
                   FROM   yourtable
                   WHERE  USER = "Matt"
                          AND type = "Opened"
                   GROUP  BY USER,
                             Type) B
               ON A.USER = B.USER
                  AND A.Type = B.Type
                  AND A.date = B.Date
```

Comment: Appreciate this as it works too.. I went for Gordon's because it was a little bit less code.

Comment: yeah clearly that is the better way.. Just want to share another way to achieve the result..thats why started the answer with another way of doing it..

Answer (score 0):

you can try using partition functions very easy its gives result for each user and performs better

```
;WITH cte
AS (
    SELECT *
        ,ROW_NUMBER() OVER (
            PARTITION BY [USER]
            ,type ORDER BY DATE ASC
            ) rnk
    FROM tablea
    )
SELECT *
FROM cte
WHERE type = 'opened'
    AND rnk = 1
```

Comment: I couldn't get this to work, but thanks for replying :)