# Access 2010 narrowing query results updated

Tags: sql, ms-access

I have a large table (tblRateandTransit, 34K rows), from which I am selecting only about 8 fields.

```
|SCAC|CarrierName|OriginCity|OState|DestCity|DState|Rate |LaneTier|
|KNIG|Knight     |York      |PA    |Canton  |NJ    |$2.99| 2      |
|HJBB|JB Hunt    |York      |PA    |Canton  |NJ    |$3.67| 2      |
| Could be 4 more different Canton carriers carriers, diff rates..|
```

I also have a table (tblFromToCityState, maybe 4 fields, 100 rows)) fed from an excel file that is a link, of what cities I need From/To info for, from the big table.

```
|FCity |FState|DestCity|DState|
|York  |PA    |Canton  |NJ    |
```

And one other small table, the Approved Carriers.

```
|SCAC|Carrier Name|
|CLLQ|Coyote      |
|HBG1|Hub Group   |
|KNIG|Knight      |
```

Ultimately my query asks from Origin_City/State to Destination_City/State, what is the best Carrier based on Tier 1 Approved first, then the best Rate if there are no Tier ones for that shipping Lane.

Phase 2 is, if the FROM City is Null, USE THE FROM State. Or if the TO City is Null, use the TO State.

If I do a simple FROM - TO - MIN(RATE) query, works great.

```
SELECT RateandTransit.[Origin City],
    RateandTransit.[Origin State],
    RateandTransit.[Destination City],
    RateandTransit.[Destination State],
    Min(RateandTransit.Rate) AS MinOfRate,
    RateandTransit.[Lane Tier]
FROM tblFromToCityState
INNER JOIN RateandTransit
    ON (tblFromToCityState.TO = RateandTransit.[Destination City])
    AND (tblFromToCityState.FROM = RateandTransit.[Origin City])
GROUP BY RateandTransit.[Origin City],
    RateandTransit.[Origin State],
    RateandTransit.[Destination City],
    RateandTransit.[Destination State],
    RateandTransit.[Lane Tier]
HAVING (((RateandTransit.[Lane Tier]) > 1))
ORDER BY RateandTransit.[Origin City] DESC,
    RateandTransit.[Lane Tier];

|Origin City|State|Dest City |State|MinRate|LaneTier|
|York       |PA   |Burlington| NJ  |$8.11  | 2      |
|York       |PA   |Canton    | MA  |$2.80  | 2      |
|etc...one line per destination city...
```

When I add the Carrier to the query, I get maybe 4 to 6 records for that FROM/TO combination, because each carrier is different so Group By does not work. For Burlington for example, I just need that $8.11 record, the least expensive shipper but I see all of them.

```
SELECT RateandTransit.[Origin City],
    RateandTransit.[Origin State],
    RateandTransit.[Destination City],
    RateandTransit.[Destination State],
    RateandTransit.SCAC,
    RateandTransit.[Carrier Legal Name],
    Min(RateandTransit.Rate) AS MinOfRate,
    RateandTransit.[Lane Tier]
FROM tblFromToCityState
INNER JOIN RateandTransit
    ON (tblFromToCityState.TO = RateandTransit.[Destination City])
    AND (tblFromToCityState.FROM = RateandTransit.[Origin City])
GROUP BY RateandTransit.[Origin City],
    RateandTransit.[Origin State],
    RateandTransit.[Destination City],
    RateandTransit.[Destination State],
    RateandTransit.SCAC,
    RateandTransit.[Carrier Legal Name],
    RateandTransit.[Lane Tier]
HAVING (((RateandTransit.[Lane Tier]) > 1))
ORDER BY RateandTransit.[Origin City] DESC,
    RateandTransit.[Lane Tier];

|Origin City|State|Dest City |State|SCAC|Carrier    |MinRate|LaneTier|
|York       |PA   |Burlington| NJ  |MPLT|Paul Miller|$8.11  | 2      |
|York       |PA   |Burlington| NJ  |XPOL|XPO Logics |$9.46  | 2      |
|York       |PA   |Burlington| NJ  |HHWY|Hub Group  |$9.60  | 2      |
|and so on...
```

I need to filter somehow, just the cheapest RATE for that FROM/TO TIER. Another question on this site answers what I need, talking about part numbers:

```
SELECT T1.*
FROM My_Table T1
INNER JOIN (
        SELECT [Ven Part Num],
            MIN(Price) AS MPrice
        FROM My_Table
        GROUP BY [Ven Part Num]
    ) T2
    ON T1.[Ven Part Num] = T2.[Ven Part Num]
    AND T1.Price = T2.MPrice
```

I am just not sure how to implement that with what I already have:

Been trying to fix using many possibilities for a week now, like using my query within a report thinking in the report I could then do a `MIN` on the `MIN(RATE)`field, or using the `MIN(RATE)` query within another query:

```
SELECT qryMinRateAll.[Origin City],
    qryMinRateAll.[Origin State],
    qryMinRateAll.[Destination City],
    qryMinRateAll.[Destination State],
    RateandTransit.SCAC,
    qryMinRateAll.MinRate,
    qryMinRateAll.[Lane Tier]
FROM qryMinRateAll
INNER JOIN RateandTransit
    ON (qryMinRateAll.[Destination City] = RateandTransit.[Destination City])
    AND (qryMinRateAll.[Origin City] = RateandTransit.[Origin City]);
```

All to no avail. I need help please!

Comment: I think subqueries sound like the way to go here, but as what you're after sounds a bit complex I think you should include the table structure and example data for tblRateandTransit and tblFromToCityState with a desired output (again shown as a table of data) to give us a more visual starting point to help. (I'm also a bit confused about the significance of the words you've capitalised).

Comment: Hi @MattHall -Yes, it is complex I think so too. I just used caps trying to paraphrase and make my post shorter. Edited above...

Comment: @MattHall i tried entering images of my tables/results, but am restricted because I am new to this site. not sure how to get the tables/ouput into the format needed here.

Comment: I know, it's a bit of nuisance isn't it? I find the best way to display a table is to type it using the stack overflow's code tool, i.e. using the {} button. If you use the code tool you can use spaces to keep everything aligned. Here's a question I asked where I posted an example table: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28438480/keep-all-columns-in-min-max-query-but-return-1-result

Comment: @MattHall - I am not quite getting the quote thing right. tried adding my tables, but formatting is all wrong.